Property 'api' does not exist on type 'MondayApi'
`    import { UpdatePersonEvent } from '@sr-connect/monday/events';
import Monday from './api/monday';
/**
* Entry point to When a person changes event
*
* @param event Object that holds When a person changes event data
* @param context Object that holds function invocation context data
*/
export default async function handlePersonChangeEvent(event: UpdatePersonEvent, context: Context): Promise<void> {
try {
    // Extract relevant data from the event
    const { pulseId, boardId } = event.event;
    
    // Define column IDs
    const personColumn = 'people__1';
    const meetingColumn = 'text2__1';

    

    // Get item details from the board
    const itemsData = await Monday.api<{ items: any[] }>(
        `query {
            boards(ids: ${boardId}) {
                items(ids: ${pulseId}) {
                    column_values(ids: ["${personColumn}", "${meetingColumn}"]) {
                        id
                        text
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
    );

    // Extract the current value of the person column
    const personValue = itemsData.data.boards[0]?.items[0]?.column_values.find((column: any) => column.id === personColumn)?.text;

    // Define the meeting text based on the person assigned
    let meetingText = '';

    switch (personValue) {
        case 'Red':
            meetingText = 'Your meeting link is this. teams/meeting1';
            break;
        case 'blue':
            meetingText = 'Your meeting link is this. teams/meeting2';
            break;
        case 'green':
            meetingText = 'Your meeting link is this. teams/meeting3';
            break;
        case 'pink':
            meetingText = 'Your meeting link is this. teams/meeting4';
            break;
        default:
            meetingText = ''; // Clear the meeting column if no specific person is assigned
            break;
    }

    // Update the meeting column with the appropriate text
    await Monday.api(
        `mutation {
            change_multiple_column_values(item_id: ${pulseId}, board_id: ${boardId}, column_values: "{\"${meetingColumn}\": {\"text\": \"${meetingText}\"}}") {
                id
            }
        }`
    );

} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling When a person changes event', error);
}
}`

Doing if else condition for monday integration. If person assigned update meeting text column to Your meeting link is... or if there is no person assigned leave meeting text link to blank.
